# Shiny can't find package RJSONIO

Tags: r, shiny

My app runs fine locally but produces this error on upload to the Shiny server:

How do I get shiny to find RJSONIO?

```
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352373+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:methods’:
2021-05-19T19:07:17.343946+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]:     runExample
2021-05-19T19:07:17.351664+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352014+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]:     runExample
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352374+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.351665+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352014+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352013+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352375+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.351271+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: 
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352012+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: The following object is masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2021-05-19T19:07:17.352375+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]:     removeClass, show
2021-05-19T19:07:17.403835+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]:   there is no package called ‘RJSONIO’
2021-05-19T19:07:17.403834+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
2021-05-19T19:07:17.403214+00:00 shinyapps[1549461]: Loading required package: RJSONIO
```

Comment: Hoe exactly are you deploying your application? Are you using `rsconnect::deployApp()`? What does your code look like that uses `RJSONIO`? Do you have an explicit call to `library(RJSONIO)`?

Comment: Explicit call to library (RJSONIO) !  Why didn't I think of that.  ty